# ESRI ArcGIS error: Zero length polylines not allowed

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, c#, polyline-creation

While writing a simple ICommand in ArcMap 10.2.1 using C# that lets you select two different point features on the map and it creates a feature in a polyline feature class with those two points as its end points (connect the dots!) using the simple logic:
grab the two selected points
add the two points to an IPointCollection
call IFeatureClass.CreateFeature() on the polyline feature class
set the new feature's shape to the point collection
call IFeature.Store() to save it.
Then we got this error: "Zero-length polylines not allowed..."
Even adding a few debug lines in to check the new feature's shape correctly has the FromPoint and ToPoint coordinates AND the Shape.Length correctly shows 204.34566 it still gives this error.

Comment: I know this is old and currently closed, but I was getting this error and discovered that it was because a `StartOperation()` was being called by a nested function within a handled edit event subscribed to from `IEditEvents_Event`.

Answer (score 1):

After troubleshooting by putting in some X Y coordinates and creating a new feature in a point feature class in a similar way it gave a better error message: "The value of the subtype code is NULL."
So we then went back to our code for creating the line feature and added a step that sets the subtype attribute before calling IFeature.Store() and it worked perfectly!  So this looks to be a "bug" in the error handling of IFeature.Store().